# Pyspark trimming all columns in a dataframe to 100 characters

Tags: python, pyspark, pyspark-schema

I am reading csv file with 350 columns all columns are type string. After reading into the Dataframe I want to substring all the columns values read form the csv file to a max of 1 to 100 characters while writing to a delta table.
Can someone kindly guide me how to perform this task. Thanks

```
for field in df.schema.fields:
    vField = df.collect()[0][field.name]
    if  vField != None:
        field.name = vField[0:20]
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `substring(column,start,end)` function from spark and iterate through all columns get only the **100** characters from each column.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a','1','a')],['i','j','k'])
df.select([substring(col(f),0,100).alias(f) for f in df.columns]).show(10,False)
#+---+---+---+
#|i  |j  |k  |
#+---+---+---+
#|a  |1  |a  |
#+---+---+---+
```